# PHP Mod Rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` which does a basic rewrite which looks like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The next condition is to remove `www.` from the URL and looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is, when I call a link such as:

```
http://somesite.com/category/subcategory/?id=123
```

and add the `www.` manually, it rewrites the URL to this:

```
http://www.somesite.com?url=category/subcategory/?123
```

The page stills load but, I've been told that's terrible for SEO. Any thoughts of how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have other `.htaccess` rules within your framework or CMS? What framework or CMS are you using? Please post your complete `.htaccess` so we can see in what order you're placing the rules.

Comment: It's not an actual framework. Working on a small project. Yes, that's all the rules within the htaccess.

Comment: Did you try change position for this rules in .htaccess ? First "remove" www and then rewrite for SEO friedly urls?

Comment: Just tried that. It generates the same result. In all these years, I've never tried to inject the www after a page loads. I got a feedback from a SEO guy who pointed that out and, I was amazed by it... although I still can't find a way to fix it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: www redirect should never come after as previous rules will take place causing your www rule not to trigger in several other cases due to the rules telling it to stop there. That is one of the reasons you have to follow a certain order while placing the rules. Your should also void using `^(.*)$` and `/$1` for domain wide redirects and use instead `^` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current issue is that you have your `WWW` redirect after your main SEO rules, this is what happens behind the scenes:

1. You access `http://somesite.com/category/subcategory/?id=123`
2. Your rules internally redirect it to `index.php?url=category/subcategory/?id=123`
3. Your last rule to redirect without the www will also take place and will ended up redirecting it to:

   ```
   http://somesite.com/?url=category/subcategory/?id=123
   ```

---

In order to fix that you would need your rules as follow:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

Which leads us to your second issue, you've been using `301` redirects so **your browser have cached some redirects** and **you will need to use a different browser temporarily to test your changes, preferable one you haven't used yet to access that site**, while you clear the cache of that browser and wait for it to completely clear out.

*Once the cache of your default browser has cleared you can use it as usual and you should get the same response.*

Comment: A good explanation. I would add to OP, that a good rule of thumb is to execute your redirects (where you actually change the URL in the browser) before your rewrites (where you silently pass the request to a new target endpoint).

Comment: @MikeBrant :P you described it better than I was trying to.